# How to horizontally center-align the content of a div by manipulating the CSS of the wrapper div only?

Tags: html, css

I have a  element, and this  element has another  element which contains a `<table>`.

For some reasons, I can not manipulate the CSS of the inner `<div>` or the `<table>` it contains.

I need to *horizontally align* the `<table>` (or the inner `<div>` which contains the `<table>`, doesn't matter, I just need to show the table aligned in the center) in the `center` of the outer `<div>`, by manipulating the CSS of the outer `<div>` only.

**The `border` and `padding` properties seem to move the outer  itself, what I need is to place  its contents in its center (horizontally). How can I do that?**

The width of the outer `<div>` is `590px`.

**PS:** I can use inline CSS only.

Comment: Show us some code, we don't understand words

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot?

Comment: create a jsfiddle please

Comment: Do you know that the inner div is the first (and only) child of outer? Then you can do .outer + div

Comment: Does the inner div or table have a specific width, or just the outer div?

Comment: @TiesonT. I think it is just the outer `div`. I can't see any set `width` for the inner `div` or the table in the Firefox Developer tools

Comment: @Benjamin Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ujxh0mjj/)

Comment: @TiesonT. Your table is elapsing the entire space available. Is it center aligned? I can't "see" that because it takes the available space. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ujxh0mjj/) is mine.

Comment: @Zarah No, that was simply a work-in-progress.

Comment: @Zarah, maybe you want it like this? http://jsfiddle.net/ujxh0mjj/12/ ... I add another `div` with `id=leftcon` inside `#leftwrapper`.

Comment: @Alexdn Thank you indeed. This works, but I just solved the problem from Danield's answer. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following 2 rules to your leftWrapper div:

```
display:flex;justify-content: center;

<div id="leftwrapper" style="width:590px;display:flex;justify-content: center; float:left; background-color:grey; overflow-y:auto; height:650px;">
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/ujxh0mjj/3/)**

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure that this meets you needs, but a simple margin rule on the table seems to do it (http://jsfiddle.net/tiesont/ujxh0mjj/1/):

```
#leftwrapper table
{
    margin: auto;
}
```

Comment: I have a bunch of constraints here, so one of them is that I can only use inline CSS and I do not have access to the HTML of the table. Infact the table is rather created in the JS (as you can see in the Fiddle).

Comment: @Zarah I saw that, but it doesn't stop the CSS from being applied. The "inline CSS" constraint should really be in your question, as that limits what we can do. Is there a specific reason it has to be inline?

Comment: I am sorry about missing that one in the question. The reason is that I am fiddling with the core code of Moodle. It is complex, and I already spent a lot of time trying to add my CSS files but it does not read them. I ended up using inline CSS for a few elements I am trying to add here and there.

Answer (score 0):

apply the css to your outer div:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
padding: - as per required;
```